# Flutter firebase_ml_vision errors with async function, getImage and pickedFile

Tags: firebase, flutter, machine-learning, firebase-mlkit, firebase-machine-learning

How to resolve the following errors:

1. The await expression can only be used in an async function.Try
   marking the function body with async.
2. Instance member 'getImage'
   can't be accessed using static access.
3. The argument type
   PickedFile can't be assigned to the parameter type File.

//Code Below

```
import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );

    final image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imageFile);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Mystify",),),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: I don't think your problems are related to any of your tags; they look like very basic language (Dart?) problems.

Comment: I have cleared the problems. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and did this.

```
await Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000))
        .whenComplete(() => () async {
              File foo = File(pickedFile.path);

              final image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(foo);
```

Answer (score -1):

use getImage instead of pickImage for flutter version 2